# Rails - Override or forward a custom Rails terminal command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code, rake

I have a very peculiar issue.

I'm using a [VS code extension](https://github.com/noku/rails-run-spec-vscode) that trigger a test runner when I press some keyboard keys which has some sort of issue. Basically I can give it some settings and it will trigger tests:

I chose:

```
"ruby.specCommand": "./bin/rails"
```

Now when I press the keyboard shortcut, I can see in the terminal that it executes:

```
$ ./bin/rails test/
```

and this does nothing. It does not trigger my minitests.

The issue is the trailing slash after the word 'test'. If the extension had triggered `./bin/rails test`, it would have worked (I tested it and it does work when I manually type this in my terminal of command).

I'm wondering how I could find a hackaround this: is it possible to create a rake task so thatb when I press my keyboard shortcut, the extension triggers in the terminal of command `./bin/rails test/` but that this is automatically "forwarded" or treated by the terminal as `./bin/rails test`. It would be like making an alias and tell the terminal of command when sb types `./bin/rails test/`, actually use instead `./bin/rails test`.

Would that be possible? I tried to create a rake task for this but failed.
If not how could I find a hack around this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be the _full_ command, like `"ruby.specCommand": "./bin/rails test"`?

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov haha yes it should be based on the extension docs but for whatever reason if i put in my settings `"ruby.specCommand": "./bin/rails test"` then when i press the keyboard shortcut, i czan see in my terminal of command `./bin/rails test test/"`
So whatever i put in my settings, the extension automatically adds the word `test/` at the end

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov that is why i'm trying to find a hack around that. The most obvious was to tell my system to put as setting `"ruby.specCommand": "./bin/rails"`, then i know due to this weird phenomenon, keyboard is going to load `./bin/rails test/`, and here i'll just hack to make this an alias or a foward to `./bin/rails test` . :-)